# onChange event is not working of input type textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to popup the value whenever the value changes in the input type textbox.
whenever the value in the textbox changes the page has to refresh.

```
<form name="project" method="post" id="project">
    <input type="text" name="prject1" id="prject1" onchange="loadlist()" />
</form>
```

and my javascript function:

```
function loadlist()
{
    var frm = window.doucument.project;
    frm.project1.value = document.getElementById("prject1").value;
    frm.action = "www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: `window.doucument != window.document`

Comment: Do you want the function to run on every key press or when a user has finished typing input?

Comment: i want the function to run when a user has finished typing input. Or for autofill values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
window.doucument.project
//-------^ Change it to document.
```

That's `document` not `doucument`.

And use absolute URLs:

```
frm.action = "http://www.google.com";
//------------^ Give http://
```